# Undefined method for array

Tags: ruby, oop

So I'm receiving the error message "undefined method 'ip_histogram' for # (NoMethodError)" with the following code

```
class CommonLog
  def initialize(logfile)
    @logfile = logfile
  end
  def readfile
    @readfile = File.readlines(@logfile).map { |line|
      line.split()
    }
    @readfile = @readfile.to_s.split(" ")
  end
  def ip_histogram
    @ip_count = 0
    @readfile.each_index { |index|
      if (@readfile[index] =~ /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/ )
        puts @readfile[index]
        puts @ip_count += 1
      end
    }
  end
end

my_file = CommonLog.new("test_log")
cleaned_file = my_file.readfile
puts cleaned_file.ip_histogram
```

I'm trying to read the array in and check it with regex. It works if I take the code out of the method and just throw it into the main program, but I'd like to know why it doesn't work as a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning the results of `CommonLog#readfile` to a new variable `cleaned_file`.  You didn't supply any input but I'm going to assume @readfile is an `array` at this point.

That means your code is going to assume there's an instance method `ip_histogram` on the `Array` class when in fact there is not.

You'll simply want to run these in sequence to get the result you're after:

```
clog = CommonLog.new("test_log")
clog.readfile
clog.ip_histogram
```

The primary difference here is that we're not using the return value of `readfile` as it only needs to set the variable in the method for `ip_histogram` to work.

Comment: Ah, that fixed it right away!  All methods fully functional, thanks so much for your help! You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `my_file.readfile` is an array. Unless you defined `ip_histogram` in `Array` class, you cannot call it on `cleaned_file`.

To define `ip_histogram` on `Array` (with different definition than in your code):

```
class Array
  def ip_histogram
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: How would I define ip_histogram on Array, define it on the Array class? Inherit the Array class into the CommonLog class?